Graphing a function which is a product or sum of 2 functions?
Background: I was solving the last exercise of a chapter from S.L. Loney's Trigonometry book, where the exercise was to graph functions like sin(x) + cos(x). Now, here we are supposed to manipulate the equations, like expressing it as cosine or sine in the above case, or somewhere nearly related to sines or cosines of known angles.
Now the problem is in questions like sin(x).cos(x), we can easily express it as a sine or cosine using some formulas, but in other cases including non-trigonometric ones, it might not be so. Therefore, the straightforward question is if there is any way to graph such functions which are a product or sum of two other functions, directly, without the cumbersome process of plotting points.
My progress: Literally none. I've tried to search on YouTube or Google for such a thing, but I can't find one (hopefully I typed the wrong keywords). Also, I've used Geogebra for plotting those graphs and trying to find out some relations, like maybe something like interference of waves (I just know that's a thing too, not the mathematics), but sin(x).cos(x) even has the maximum value as halved of sine or cosine, and some other functions look nothing like their parents.

There is not really any method for this in general, other than just making the list of points $(x_1, f(x_1)), (x_2, f(x_2))…$

hmph... thats just sad...

There is no method to graph functions in general other than just listing points, let alone products or sums of functions

i meant if we could derive complex ones from simple ones.

Please see How to show that $f(x) = \sin x + \cos x$ is sinusoidal (alternative).

We have a fairly quick way of doing the sum of two functions. The same is not true for the product, although you can get a bit of intuition into graphing a product.
The quickest way to graph a sum is to superimpose the two, taking the net value when adding each of their values at a point.
To graph a product (of two functions), take one of the functions. Then, look at the behaviour of the other one. The other one acts as a changing scale factor of the other, possibly damping it or reflecting it in the x-axis. For example:
$$f(x) = xsin(x)$$
Let's just focus on the $sin(x)$. We all know its shape: sinusoidal, periodic. Then, we notice that when we multiply by $x$, for $x \geq 1$, we are scaling it up, meaning that its peaks and troughs become gradually more and more extreme, and its oscillations more extreme, as $x \to \infty$. For $x \leq -1$, we are doing what we just described but mirroring it in the x-axis. For $|x| <1$ we are 'scaling down', and for negative $x$ in this range we are also reflecting.
Graphing sums and products will fundamentally require us evaluating the individual functions at all points we graph the sum/product at, but at the end of the day with a good understanding of how to transform a function, one can have good intuition into how a graph may look overall.
In terms of the specific functions you have described, and points you raised:

This mathematics fundamentally gives us good ways to describe wave interference, so you will want a bit of insight into this before tackling that.
The $\cos{(x)} \cdot \sin{(x)}$ example is an interesting one! Both of the functions have constraints on their maxima, and take their maxima/minima at different $x$ values. In terms of trig, we have $$cos^2 = 1- sin^2.$$
To optimise them, we use the idea of optimising a product where if they sum to a value, we want each to be half of that value, i.e. $$sin^2 = cos^2 = \frac{1}{2},$$ giving in turn $$sin(x) = cos(x) = \frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}.$$
From here, you get our max. value by multiplying the sin and cos together.

